# Why my ajax call is make page unresponsive on second call?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, material-design

I have a ajax call as below. It is working fine on first call. But when I call it for the second time, it is making the page unresponsive. I'm not able to figure out why. This is present in document ready call. My backend is getting called in second attempt but it is getting stuck inside success. Here is how I'm calling it.

```
$('#upload-form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        uploadPDF();
    });
```

Here is my method making ajax call.

```
function uploadPDF() {
        var form = $('#upload-form')[0];
        var data = new FormData(form);
    
        /* call to upload api */
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: "/uploadPdf",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#upload-form').trigger("reset");
                $('#courses-container').show().siblings().hide();
                var toastHTML = '<span>' + data.success + '</span>';
                M.toast({
                    html: toastHTML,
                    classes: 'teal lighten-1'
                });
            },
            error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#upload-form').trigger("reset");
                var toastHTML = '<span>' + textStatus.responseJSON.error +
                    '</span>';
                M.toast({
                    html: toastHTML,
                    classes: 'red lighten-1'
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your server becomes unresponsive on the second attempt. Using `async: false` with `$.ajax` is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @RoboRobok thanks. That was the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async: false` makes it a [synchronous request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests). It freezes the browser until the request is finished. This feature is deprecated on modern browsers and should never be used in modern code.

> Synchronous XHR requests often cause hangs on the web. But developers typically don't notice the problem because the hang only manifests with poor network conditions or when the remote server is slow to respond. Synchronous XHR is now in deprecation state. The recommendation is that developers move away from the synchronous API and instead use asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 0):

- Make this ajax request as Async true. it will help in parallel execution of your request whether first one is completed or not.
- Optional - Try to change content type.

Below code worked fine for me, please try and do let me know in case your issue will still not get resolve.

```
function uploadPDF() {
    var form = $('#upload-form')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);

    /* call to upload api */
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "/uploadPdf",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#upload-form').trigger("reset");
            $('#courses-container').show().siblings().hide();
            var toastHTML = '<span>' + data.success + '</span>';
            M.toast({
                html: toastHTML,
                classes: 'teal lighten-1'
            });
        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#upload-form').trigger("reset");
            var toastHTML = '<span>' + textStatus.responseJSON.error +
                '</span>';
            M.toast({
                html: toastHTML,
                classes: 'red lighten-1'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Rest of your Code looks fine.